# RShiny: Problem with creating .docx file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the [`officer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/index.html) package to save data in a shiny app as a word file. The strange thing is, it works in the IDE, but not in the app. Futher, I do not get an error, simply put: nothing happens.

This is what happens in the IDE:

```
library(magrittr)
library(officer)

x<-'square'

doc <- read_docx()

doc <- doc %>%
      body_add_par(paste('My favorite shape is',input$id), style = "Normal") %>%
      body_add_table(iris,style = "table_template")

    print(doc,target = "doc1.docx")
```

> This runs correctly, creating the Word (.docx) file as seen here:

[image: docx]

However, when trying to include it in Shiny, nothing happens:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(officer)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput('id','Choose shape:',
                 choices = c('Triangle','Circle','Square')),

  actionButton('submit','Submit Form', icon = icon('table'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  WriteWord<-function() {

    doc <- read_docx()

    doc <- doc %>%
      body_add_par(paste('My favorite shape is',input$id), style = "Normal") %>%
      body_add_table(iris,style = "table_template")
    print(doc,target = "doc1.docx")
  }

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    WriteWord()
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**There are no errors**, nothing happens. I click the actionbutton and there is not file created. Odd.

Comment: What library is print() located in?  Check relative path names?  By default, I think Shiny will output to /www directory in the application server path, unless another resource is defined.

Comment: I ran your script and it executed fine, with doc1.docx and the iris data. Running on my local machine.  Output was at the current location of getwd() (and not in /www).

Comment: You ran it in Shiny, right?

Comment: Yes, I did.  And clicked the button to create it.  Maybe theres a write permissions issue?

Comment: idk but today it is working ODD